# sharing Variables between Visual C++ Projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am using OpenCV to find golf balls. I have already found the coordinates of the ball and I now want to send these coordinates to another VC++ project which does the communication of the project. I want to know how do I declare the variable so that it can be accessed in another project in the solution

Answer (score 1):

If the two projects run separate processes, you will need [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) (inter-process communication). There's a [Boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) for that.

If your projects run only one process, say one is an `exe` and one is a `dll`, you can link your `exe` to the `dll` and pass the values via a global used by both the `exe` and the `dll` (not recommended) or via function calls (i.e. create an object from the `dll` and call a set function with your values or something like that).